# Recycler View Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have got this stack trace though crashlytics. I have no idea where the issue is.

Is there any alternative of StaggeredGridLayoutManager that I can use to get a listview like layout.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: start < 0 || end > len. start=-1, end=11, len=11
   at java.util.Arrays.checkStartAndEnd(Arrays.java:1745)
   at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:803)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$LazySpanLookup.invalidateAfter(SourceFile:2404)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.handleUpdate(SourceFile:1373)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onItemsRemoved(SourceFile:1327)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$6.dispatchUpdate(SourceFile:725)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$6.onDispatchFirstPass(SourceFile:716)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.dispatchFirstPassAndUpdateViewHolders(SourceFile:316)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.dispatchAndUpdateViewHolders(SourceFile:302)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.applyRemove(SourceFile:182)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.preProcess(SourceFile:103)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags(SourceFile:2767)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(SourceFile:2538)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1489)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:940)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:135)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5134)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2331)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5739)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5380)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This is what I am doing to handle click listeners in one of the adapter

```
     @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  holder.relative.setClickable(true);

    holder.relative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null)
                itemClickListener.onClick(v, position);
            else
                AppConfig.log("itemClickLestener was null");
        }
    });

    holder.relative.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null)
                itemClickListener.onLongClick(v, position);
            return true;
        }
    });
  return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like you were trying to call **getAdapterPosition()** while Recycler View layouts are not calculated (possibly triggered by a notifyDataSetChanged() call).

always handle it like this

```
final int position = getAdapterPosition();
if(positon != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
    // you can trust the adapter position
    // do whatever you intend to do with this position
}
```

The documentation clearly states the following

> if you want to access the item in the adapter on a ViewHolder click, you should use getAdapterPosition(). Beware that these methods may not be able to calculate adapter positions if notifyDataSetChanged() has been called and new layout has not yet been calculated. For this reasons, you should carefully handle NO_POSITION or null results from these methods.

**UPDATE**

Now that you have finally posted some code. here are some things you should consider.

1. Do not pass final parameters inside onBindViewHolder. By the time the OnClickListener is fired the position is not guaranteed to be the same as you think it would be. So do this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.relative.setClickable(true);
       //do other stuff
   }
   ```
2. DO NOT assign any listeners inside onBindViewHolder method. As the view gets recycled you end up setting listeners multiple times to the same view. Instead, set it inside the view holder class or onCreateViewHolder method like below

   ```
   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

       //setting listeners on creation
       myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               final int position = getAdapterPosition();
               if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                   //do whatever you want with the clicked position
               }
           }
       });

      //return the view holder
      return new MyViewHolder(myView);
   }
   ```

   Or in the ViewHolder class

   ```
   public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //setting listeners inside viewHolder class
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                   if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                       //do whatever you want with the clicked position
                   }
                }
             });
           }
      }
   ```

Fixing the above may fix your problem. I highly recommend you to check the Google Dev Summit 2015 video about RecyclerView. It is really interesting and they talk about the ins and outs of the RecyclerView. They also mention why not to pass final parameters inside onBinViewHolder. Click [here](https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=34m50s) to check out the exact moment in the video in which they talk about it.

Comment: I have my code now using new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 1) what you think of this,  I have not found any code using getAdapterPosition(

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the layout manager you use. Can you post your adapter class?

Comment: I was using StaggeredGridLayoutManager in three Adapters . I dont know where exactly this issues is arising from. So not able to share any detail

Comment: I would start by looking at the adapters that have implemented **OnClickListener** in any of its ViewHolders. Check how you retrieve the adapter position and move from there!

Comment: @RajnishMishra I have updated my answer. Please check if it works for you

Comment: It's really great . I will check it tomorrow and most probably I am going to select your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error will be occuring in your on bindview where you will be using the data of your arraylist. Make sure you have used **position -1** value of the arraylist.

Comment: I have my code now using new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 1) what you think of this

Comment: @RajnishMishra this is fine but can you just show us the bindviewholder?

Comment: Is this error reproducible if you click on the last element of your recyclerview? If so, consider  writing itemClickListener.onClick(v, position -1); instead of itemClickListener.onClick(v, position);

Comment: I think position starts from 0 let me check